# assign variable and detect null in on if statement

Tags: javascript

How can we assign a variable and also detect if the result is null or false in one if statement?

```js
function getNodes(selector) {
    var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    if(!nodeList.length) { return null; } else { return nodeList; }
}

var divs;

if( ! divs = getNodes('div') ) { // ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side
    console.log('no divs found');
}

if( divs = getNodes('div') && !divs ) {  // does not work
    console.log('no divs found');
}

if( divs = getNodes('div') && divs==null ) {  // does not work
    console.log('no divs found');
}
```

```html
<p>
no divs here
</p>
```

Simply `if(divs = getNodes('div'))` does work but that is not what I am after. I need to catch if it's  null or assign it in one statement.

**Solution 1** `if( !(divs = getNodes('div')) )`

**Solution 2** `if( (divs = getNodes('div')) == null )`

Thank you everyone

Comment: Convert the assignment to an expression by wrapping it in the parentheses (in the first if).

Comment: Couldn't you just assign the variable first, and then do the check later?

var divs = getNodes('div'); if (!divs) // falsy

Comment: @d30jeff certainly, but i'm trying to do both at once.

Comment: @Teemu that was it, thanks!

Comment: What is the benefit of doing it in one step other than being not really readable?

Comment: @epascarello I find it easily readable. Less lines, more screen space, I can see more of my code at once, smaller file size, minifies better, etc.

Comment: @epascarello I wouldn't say that's an appropriate dup target. This is more about operator precedence. Good reading, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`divs = getNodes('div')` will basically return the value assigned to `divs`.
That's how you are able to do `a = b = 2`.

In your case, you can basically do:

and so, `((div = getNodes('div')) == null)` evaluates to `true`.

Which means, you can basically do:

```
if((div = getNodes('div')) === null){
    //do Whatever
}
```

Or if you just want to check if its null and you know it will never evaluate to false (or if false is also an error condition), you can:

```
if(!(div = getNodes('div'))){
    //do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're trying to accomplish.

```js
function getNodes(selector) {
    var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    if(!nodeList.length) { return null; } else { return nodeList; }
}

var divs;

if( !(divs = getNodes('div')) ) { // ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side
    console.log('no divs found');
}

console.log(divs);
```